# FeignClient name placeholder

Tags: java, spring, feign

I Have a FeignClient interface with a name that I want to load from my `application.yml` file so I did this :

```
@FeignClient(name = "${edgeServer}", configuration = BeansConfiguration.class)
```

And in my `yml` file :

```
edgeServer: edge-server
```

But I get an exception at runtime :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service id not legal hostname (${edgeServer})
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.getName(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClient(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:181) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClients(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:92) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]

So is there any solution to that issue, else how can I make my name attribute injected from my yml properties ?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but fail, injection of property works. Can you show your BeansConfiguration? Maybe it have some specific properties

Answer (score 0):

updated your line

```
@FeignClient(name = "${edgeServer}", configuration = BeansConfiguration.class)
```

with

```
@FeignClient(name = @Value("${edgeServer}"), configuration = BeansConfiguration.class)
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I used property **value** instead of **name** and it worked fine for me.Check the below code snippet.

```
application.yml-->

    stock:
      service: STOCK-SERVICE
    
 Feign client interface-->

    @FeignClient(value="${stock.service:STOCK-SERVICE}")
```

**Note**- If stock.service is not configured in application.yml then the default configuration configured at feign client will be considered

Answer (score -1):

Have you added `@PropertySource("classpath:applciation.yml")` on top of class?